# Correct MIME type for multipart MJPEG stream over http?

Tags: mime-types, mjpeg

Chrome always throws a warning for my MJPEG stream:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type multipart/x-mixed-replace
```

Is there maybe a better MIME type to use that can fix this? Can I just use 'Image', even though it IS a multipart stream?

Answer (score 6):

From different resources across the web, the more commonly employed `MIME` type for `M-JPEG` i.e. `Motion JPEG` is `video/x-motion-jpeg`. Only `GStreamer` has a slightly different view as it employs `video/x-jpeg` as indicated in this [table of video `MIME` types](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/section-types-definitions.html#table-video-types).

The web resources for `MJPEG` `MIME` types are:

1. [htmlquick](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/mime-types.html)
2. [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)
3. [Harvard Site](http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/systems/wax/wax-public-help/mimetypes.htm)
4. [IBM Site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cmgmt/v8r3m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vc.doc/vidprmst24.htm)

Comment: OP is not playing a video stored on the server, but grabbing a stream.